# How to find closer maven repository close to my home

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I am wondering how to find the maven repository close to my home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml)'s there official central repository mirror listing (as xml-file) and [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories)'s another list of central repository mirrors.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the listing at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories is problematic.  Is Central in San Francisco, California or in St. Louis, Missouri? (I guess this is an inadvertent lesson on why code, or even xml, should not be commented). To make things more confusing, the owner of the domain (according to http://whois.net/whois/maven.org) is in Fulton, MD.

Maybe the question was not "Where are the repositories?" (which esaj answered), but really:
"*How* can I find the maven repository *closest* to my home?"

That question bugged me, too.

On the other hand, does it really matter, given how fast packets travel across the world?

But it still bugged me.

There are two ways to find out which host is the closest:

1. Open a browser, go to http://freegeoip.net, and type in the hostname. If you know where you are, then you can go to GoogleMaps, get directions, and check the distance.
2. Open a terminal window, and ping the hostname to find the average round trip transit time in milliseconds. This will give you the electronic distance, which is really more important for file transfer times.
3. Repeat for each hostname (i.e. about 40 times, if you're looking at the download sites for Maven itself)
4. Sort by the distance measured by the GoogleMaps directions, or by the transit time.

For 40 hosts you could probably do that manually in 20 tedious minutes, but a true professional would rather spend a few hours writing the Selenium and java code that could do it in 5 minutes.

In my copious amounts of spare time, I threw together only half the job (i.e. no Selenium):

```
public class ClosestUrlFinder {

    /**
     * Find out where a hostname is.
     * Adapted from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
     * Send HTTP GET requests to: freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname}
     * The API supports both HTTP and HTTPS.
     * Supported formats are csv, xml or json.
     * E.G. http://freegeoip.net/xml/www.poolsaboveground.com
     * returns <Response><Ip>207.58.184.93</Ip><CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
     * <CountryName>United States</CountryName><RegionCode>VA</RegionCode><RegionName>Virginia</RegionName>
     * <City>Mclean</City><ZipCode>22101</ZipCode>
     * <Latitude>38.9358</Latitude><Longitude>-77.1621</Longitude>
     * <MetroCode>511</MetroCode><AreaCode>703</AreaCode></Response>
     * @param urlOrHostname
     * @return
     */
    public String getUrlLocation(String urlOrHostname) {
        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
        BufferedReader in = null;
        URL urlObject;
        StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
            urlObject = new URL("http://freegeoip.net/xml/" + urlOrHostname);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + urlOrHostname);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try { in.close(); } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }


    /*
     * Fixed version of code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address
     */
    public String runDosCommand(List<String> command) 
    {
        String string = "", result = "";
        ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process;
        try {
            process = pBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            //System.out.println("Standard output of the command:");
            while ((string = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(string);
                result = result + "\n" + string;
            }
            while ((string = stdError.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("stdError: "+ string);
                result = result + "\nstdError: " + string;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error with command "+command);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String pingUrl(String url) {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        String averagePingTime = "0", geoText = "", loss = "";
        command.add("ping");
        command.add("-n");
        command.add("2");
        url = url.replace("ftp://", "");
        url = Utils.first(url.replace("/", " "));
        url = Utils.first(url.replace(":", " "));
        command.add(url);
        System.out.println("command is: "+command);
        String pingResult = runDosCommand(command);
        String timeoutString = "Request timed out";
        String timeout = Utils.grep(timeoutString, pingResult);
        String noHostString = "Ping request could not find host";
        String noHost = Utils.grep(noHostString, pingResult);
        String unreachableString = "Destination net unreachable";
        String unreachable = Utils.grep(unreachableString, pingResult);
        if (Utils.isNullOrEmptyString(timeout) && Utils.isNullOrEmptyString(noHost)
                && Utils.isNullOrEmptyString(unreachable)) {
            String lostString = "Lost =";
            loss = Utils.grep(lostString, pingResult);
            int index = loss.indexOf(lostString);
            loss = loss.substring(index);
            if (!loss.equals("Lost = 0 (0% loss),")) { 
                System.out.println("Non-zero loss for " + url);
                averagePingTime = "0"; 
            } else {
                String replyString = "Reply from";
                String replyFrom = Utils.grep(replyString, pingResult);
                String ipAddress = Utils.nth(replyFrom, 3);
                System.out.println("reply Ip="+ipAddress.replace(":", ""));
                String averageString = "Average =";
                averagePingTime = Utils.grep(averageString, pingResult);
                index = averagePingTime.indexOf(averageString);
                averagePingTime = averagePingTime.substring(index);
                averagePingTime = Utils.last(averagePingTime).replace("ms", "");

                String xml = getUrlLocation(url);        
                //System.out.println("xml="+xml);
                geoText = extractTextFromXML(xml);
                System.out.println("geoText="+geoText);
            }
        } else {
            averagePingTime = "0"; 
            System.out.println("Error. Either could not find host, Request timed out, or unreachable network for " + url);; 
        }
        System.out.println("Results for " + url + " are: " + loss + " " + averagePingTime + " miliseconds.");
        return url + " " + averagePingTime + " " + geoText ;
    }


    public ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> pingManyUrls() {
        ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> mirrorTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] urls = Utils.readTextFile("resources/MavenUrls.txt").split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("Start pingManyUrls with "+urls.length + " urls.");
        for (String url : urls) {
            url = url.trim();
            System.out.println("************************************\npingManyUrls: Check Url " + url);
            if (arrayListContainsKey(url, mirrorTimeList)) {
                System.out.println("Key " + url + " already in array.");
            } else {
                String pingInfo = pingUrl(url);
                String averagePingString = Utils.nth(pingInfo, 2);
                if (!averagePingString.equals("0")) {
                    int averagePingMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(averagePingString);
                    pingInfo = Utils.rest(pingInfo); //chop the first term (the url)
                    pingInfo = Utils.rest(pingInfo); // chop the 2nd term (the time)
                    url = url + " " + pingInfo;
                    System.out.println(" Adding Key " + url + " " + averagePingMilliseconds + " to array.");
                    Entry<String,Integer> urlTimePair = new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(url, averagePingMilliseconds);
                    mirrorTimeList.add(urlTimePair); 
                } else { System.out.println("Url " + url + " has a problem and therefore will be not be included."); }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(mirrorTimeList, new Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare (Entry<String,Integer> pair1, Entry<String,Integer> pair2) {
                return  pair1.getValue().compareTo(pair2.getValue());
            }
        });
        return mirrorTimeList;
    }


    public boolean arrayListContainsKey(String key, ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> arrayList) {
        for (Entry<String,Integer> keyValuePair : arrayList) {
            //System.out.println(keyValuePair.getKey() + " =? " + key);
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(keyValuePair.getKey())) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String extractFirstTagContents(Element parentElement, String tagname) {
        NodeList list = parentElement.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
        if (list != null && list.getLength()>0) {
            String contents = list.item(0).getTextContent();
            System.out.println("Tagname=" + tagname + " contents="+contents);
            return contents;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String extractTextFromXML(String xml) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        String content = "";
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
            Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
            content = rootElement.getTextContent();
            //System.out.println("content="+content);
//            String city = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "City");
//            String state = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "RegionName");
//            String zipCode = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "ZipCode");
//            String country = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "CountryName");
//            String latitude = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "Latitude");
//            String longitude = extractFirstTagContents(rootElement, "Longitude");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException saxex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            saxex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting ClosestUrlFinder");
        ClosestUrlFinder ping = new ClosestUrlFinder();
        ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> mirrorList = ping.pingManyUrls();
        System.out.println("Final Results, sorted by trip travel time (out of "+mirrorList.size()+" successful pings).");
        for (Entry<String,Integer> urlTime : mirrorList) {
            System.out.println(urlTime.getKey() + " " + urlTime.getValue());
        }
    }

}  // End of Class
```

Where the data in MavenUrls.txt is:

```
apache.claz.org
apache.cs.utah.edu
apache.mesi.com.ar
apache.mirrors.hoobly.com
apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net
apache.mirrors.pair.com
apache.mirrors.tds.net
apache.osuosl.org
apache.petsads.us
apache.spinellicreations.com
apache.tradebit.com
download.nextag.com
ftp.osuosl.org
ftp://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/ 
mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/
mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/
mirror.metrocast.net/apache/
mirror.nexcess.net/apache/
mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/
mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/
mirror.sdunix.com/apache/
mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/
mirror.tcpdiag.net/apache/
mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/
mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/
mirrors.sonic.net/apache/
psg.mtu.edu/pub/apache/
supergsego.com/apache/
www.bizdirusa.com
www.bizdirusa.com/mirrors/apache/
www.carfab.com/apachesoftware/
www.dsgnwrld.com/am/
www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/
www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/
www.interior-dsgn.com/apache/
www.motorlogy.com/apache/
www.picotopia.org/apache/
www.poolsaboveground.com/apache/
www.trieuvan.com/apache/
www.webhostingjams.com/mirror/apache/
```

And my Utils class includes the following:

```
/**
 * Given a string of words separated by spaces, returns the first word.
 * @param string
 * @return
 */
public static String first(String string) {
    if (isNullOrEmptyString(string)) { return ""; }
    string = string.trim();
    int index = string.indexOf(" ");  //TODO: shouldn't this be "\\s+" to handle double spaces and tabs? That means regexp version of indexOf
    if (index<0) { return string; }
    return string.substring(0, index);
}

/**
 * Given a string of words separated by spaces, returns the rest of the string after the first word.
 * @param string
 * @return
 */
public static String rest(String string) {
    if (isNullOrEmptyString(string)) { return ""; }
    string = string.trim();
    int index = string.indexOf(" ");  //TODO: shouldn't this be "\\s+" to handle double spaces and tabs? That means regexp version of indexOf
    if (index<0) { return ""; }
    return  string.substring(index+1);
} 

public static String grep(String regexp, String multiLineStringToSearch) {
    String result = "";
    //System.out.println("grep for '"+ regexp + "'");
    String[] lines = multiLineStringToSearch.split("\\n");
    //System.out.println("grep input string contains "+ lines.length + " lines.");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    for (String line : lines) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            //System.out.println("grep found match="+ line);
            result = result + "\n" + line;
        }
    }
    return result.trim();
}

/**
 * Given the path and name of a plain text (ascii) file,
 * reads it and returns the contents as a string.
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 */
public static String readTextFile(String filePath) {   
    BufferedReader reader;
    String result = "";
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(lineSeparator);
        }
        reader.close();
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
        logger.info("readTextFile: Read "+filePath+" with "+ counter + " lines, "+result.length()+" characters.");
        return result;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.fatal("readTextFile: Could not find file "+filePath+".");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.fatal("readTextFile: Could not read file "+filePath+".");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

public static boolean isNullOrEmptyString(String s) {
    return (s==null || s.equals(""));
}

/**
 * Given a string of words separated by one or more whitespaces, returns the Nth word.
 * @param string
 * @return
 */
public static String nth(String string, int n) {
    string = string.trim();
    String[] splitstring = string.split("\\s+");
    String result = "";
    if (splitstring.length<n) { return ""; }
    else {
        result = splitstring[n - 1];
    }
    return result.trim();
}

/**
 * Given a string of words separated by spaces, returns the last word.
 * @param string
 * @return
 */
public static String last(String string) {
    return  string.substring(string.trim().lastIndexOf(" ")+1, string.trim().length());
}
```

Enjoy!