# Find an IP's origin (Internet or Intranet) in JAVA?

Tags: java, ip, intranet

Normally i can ping an IP programmatically.But it does not return that IP is in internet or intranet.I want to find whether the pinging IP is in internet or intranet.is there any way to find it.

Comment: You can specify a range for your intranet addresses, all those which do not fall in that range would be internet IP Addresses.

Comment: I am really interested what the code will be if there are many different network with different subnet mask.

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply ping in Java as it relies on ICMP, which is sadly not supported in Java

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ping.html

Use sockets instead

Hope it helps

Thanks to [aretai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124682/aretai) for  [java code to ping an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address)

But I find sthg like that https://gist.github.com/madan712/4509039

Answer (score 0):

What you *can* tell is whether the IP address is a "[private range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Private_networks)" address, this is an address in a range which is not valid for use on the public internet and specifically meant for intranet use. For example any address in the range 192.168.* or 10.*.

You can do this using the [InetAddress.isSiteLocal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isSiteLocalAddress%28%29) method. Of course if your company doesn't use private range IP addresses for its intranet, this is not going to work.