# How to design ping application in java..which should take TTL, Payload, number of packets sent etc as arguments

Tags: java

I don't know how to access header fields of a packet and how to generate ICMP and IP packet in java.

```
  InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  int port = 7;

  DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ia, port);
```

Is this a right way or I am going in wrong direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java code to ping an IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong direction. It is not possible to send ICMP packets in pure Java.

It would require to implement it in another language like C and call it via JNI.