# getByName() - how to elaborate on cause?

Tags: java, networking

With [InetAddress.getByName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-) I would like to be able to distinguish between

- The name service replied, and the result was negative

and

- the name service did not reply (no connectivity to DNS server or whatever)

I believe there's a huge difference between the two in terms of support, i.e. telling someone where to look for the problem. It's the difference between a problem with the argument vs an infrastructure problem.

So how can I distinguish between the two?

As I see it there's just [UnknownHostException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) in both cases and the message text is similar. Any good ideas ?

Code snippet to clarify:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    if ( ..... ) {
        System.out.println("Name server replied but did not know \"" + hostname + "\"");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name server could not be contacted");
    }
}
```

To be specific: what would `.....` be in the example ??

Answer (score -1):

As an extension, you could always code into your try/catch an extra function to ping the IP address given to see the response (as defined in this ([java code to ping an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address)) posting).

By doing so, you could use your function and then verify exactly why the problem occurred. However I might just recommend testing this in advance if possible (e.g. before you try to connect directly).

Comment: Ouch. That's a really bad idea. Ping means ICMP which may be blocked while TCP/UDP is not, i.e. such test will give false results in my scenario. I'm interested in whether or not the *name server* replies, not the endpoint used in the name lookup. Your suggestion would additionally require me to know the DNS server IP.

Comment: Ping what IP address? The IP address is what he's trying to determine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use methods inherited by this class from java.lang.Throwable class(see java api) or build custom exception in which you can check two conditions one for negative and null.

Comment: Not sure I understand. How can I control the nature and contents of  exceptions thrown by [getByName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-) ? That class is part of standard JDK, not mine.