# Which Privilege Should be Obtained for ICMP Request at Java?

Tags: java, linux, ping

I want to ping an IP via Java. When I ping from command line and track the network packages I see ICMP requests. When I ping from my application and track the network packages I see TCP requests at port 7.

I've checked the documentation of `InetAddress.isReachable()`:

> Best effort is made by the implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status while some specific ports may be accessible.
>
> A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs **if the privilege can be obtained**, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.

I can run sudo needed commands with the user that I run my Java application.

Which privilege should be obtained for my purpose? What should I check?

**PS:** I've asked this question at stackoverflow.com because of it is more related to Java problem(which Java source code requires to run) than a system problem.

Comment: @maksimov that link says that: (ICMP) usually requires administrative (root) rights but it is not my case?

Comment: This seems not a duplicate of [java code to ping an IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address) because it asks about a specific detail - the privilege mentioned in the documentation - whereas the other question is asking a more general question

Comment: Does "requires root rights" not answer your question "which privilege?"

Comment: @maksimov no it is not. I want to learn what are the privileges mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @kamaci thanks, I have retracted my comment

Comment: @maksimov Why? You are correct. 'Root privilege' is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about Linux or about Java? - Obviously, the JVM process running your program will need to have all the Linux privileges required to open a "raw" ICMP socket, just as any other process.

For one implementation see e.g. [`Java_java_net_Inet4AddressImpl_isReachable0`](http://icedtea.classpath.org/~vanaltj/webrevs/tl/patch1/jdk/src/solaris/native/java/net/Inet4AddressImpl.c.html) where it basically just boils down to:

```
/*
 * Let's try to create a RAW socket to send ICMP packets
 * This usually requires "root" privileges, so it's likely to fail.
 */
 fd = JVM_Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
 if (fd != -1) {
    /*
     * It didn't fail, so we can use ICMP_ECHO requests.
     */
     return ping4(env, fd, &him, timeout, netif, ttl);
 }

 /*
  * Can't create a raw socket, so let's try a TCP socket
  */
 ...
```