# How to check Hbase region server is up or down

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-storm

Is it possible to check whether HBase region server is up or down through Java code in our program while writing some data to HBase from Storm....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ping` from your Java code :)

More info at [How to ping via JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address)

Comment: we can ping to localhost which is our ambari server but sometimes ambari is up and running but it may happen that our hbase region server or master is down....so how to predict that our region server is up???

Comment: You can ping hbase region serves as well. Get the ips of the region servers and ping them

Answer (score 0):

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.master", "10.2.210.46:60000");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","10.2.210.46");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf); 
    System.out.println(admin.isMasterRunning());
```