# Ping multiple servers in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program which sends a ping request to the servers. The list is large and if an `IP` is unreachable it takes time to go to the next `IP`.

I wish that, for every `IP`, it should create a new thread & process all of them simultaneously.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 89; i++)
{
     ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", isWindows? "-n" : "-c", "1", buttons[i].getText());
     Process proc = processBuilder.start();
     returnVal = proc.waitFor();                       
}
```

How can I make this code to ping all `IP`s, each in a separate thread ?

Comment: See [java code to ping an IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address).

Comment: Looks like a perfect situation to use CompletableFuture class shipped with Java 8. Check it out!

Comment: Those who marked as duplicate, I have not asked to ping and IP address. I want a way to simultaniously start ping of IP address.

Comment: Just a word of caution. Doing this for a large number of hosts will be **very** slow. A better approach is to do the ping from within java, rather than spawn another process to do the ping. You can read more in this other SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11508356/608820

Comment: @bogojane you should ping from within java... you could also use async IO to start pinging different ips without waiting for a response from other sockets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about doing without `ProcessBuilder` as suggested by others also.

I have three classes - `PingParallel` is my main class, `PingTask` is the task performed by each thread, and `PingResult` is having result code (we can add some more info also, status message etc.).

> *PingParallel*

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class PingParallel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalIps = 89;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalIps);
        List<Future<PingResult>> list = new ArrayList<Future<PingResult>>();
        Callable<PingResult> callable = null;
        for(int i=0; i< totalIps; i++){
            callable = new PingTask("127.0.0"+i); // Get the ipAddres buttons[i].getText());
            Future<PingResult> future = executor.submit(callable);
            list.add(future);
        }
        for(Future<PingResult> fut : list){
            try {
                System.out.println(new Date()+ "::"+fut.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

> *PingTask*

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class PingTask implements Callable<PingResult> {

  private String ipAddress;

  public PingTask(String ipAddress) {
    this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
  }

  @Override
  public PingResult call() {
    InetAddress inet = null;
    try {
      inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
      int resultCode = inet.isReachable(5000) ? 0 : -1;
      return new PingResult(ipAddress, resultCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return new PingResult(ipAddress, -1);
    }
  }
}
```

> *PingResult*

```
package com.test.thread;

public class PingResult {

  private String ipAddress;
  private int resultCode;

  public PingResult(String ipAddress, int resultCode) {
    this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    this.resultCode = resultCode;
  }

  public String getIpAddress() {
    return ipAddress;
  }

  public int getResultCode() {
    return resultCode;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "IpAddress :: "+ ipAddress + " Result Code : "+ resultCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ProcessBuilder does invoke a new process, but you are effectively killing the parallelism by calling waitFor, since that will wait for the first process to complete before launching the next, making the calls sequential instead.
You could either use PB and skip the wait calls, or perhaps use ordinary java threads wrapping calls to Runtime.exec instead.

Comment: If I remove the line `returnVal = proc.waitFor();`, then how can I know if host is reachable or not ?

Comment: Rather than calling the slow, blocking `proc.waitFor` immediately you add `proc` to an `ArrayList`. Once you have all these `proc`s running in parallel have a second loop that goes through the `ArrayList` and calls `proc.waitFor`, most of which will return quickly now, since they are all running in parallel. That said, I agree with everyone who suggests not using Process for this and using native Java instead.