# Java/JavaFX - check if internet connection exists upon trying db connection

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx, connection

Let's say I have created a simple login window in JavaFX that checks if the username and password match each other by connecting to a postgresql database, and upon success logs the user in.

Now, this works perfectly fine as long as an internet connection exists.

However, if there's no internet connection the JVM repeatedly spews out PSQLExceptions and the application freezes for somewhat a minute or so. I thought I was catching these in my connection class. It is caused by SocketTimeoutException.

Does anyone have any tips regarding how I could handle this such that an error message would display in the GUI rather than freezing and exceptions?

My connection class looks like this:

```
public class DBConnection {
/* DB credentials, modify as needed */
private static final String HOST     = "<HOST>";
private static final String DATABASE = "<DATABASE>";
private static final String USERNAME = "<USERNAME>";
private static final String PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>";
private static final String PORT     = "5432";

/* !!DO NOT EDIT BELOW!! */
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private static final String URL         = "jdbc:postgresql://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/" + DATABASE;

private static final ComboPooledDataSource POOL = new ComboPooledDataSource();

private static Connection conn = null;

public static void Connect() throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException{
    try {
        POOL.setDriverClass(JDBC_DRIVER);
    }catch (PropertyVetoException e){
        System.out.println("Could not locate JDBC driver");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    //Connection parameters
    POOL.setJdbcUrl(URL);
    POOL.setUser(USERNAME);
    POOL.setPassword(PASSWORD);

    //Pool properties
    POOL.setMinPoolSize(3);
    POOL.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    POOL.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    POOL.setMaxStatements(180);

    try {
        conn = POOL.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not establish connection to database");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
public static ResultSet ExecuteQuery(String query) throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    CachedRowSet crs = null;
    try {
        Connect();
        System.out.println("Select statement: " + query + "\n");
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem occurred at executeQuery operation: " + e);
        throw e;
    }finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, st, rs);
    }
    return crs;
}
public static void ExecuteUpdate(String query) throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try {
        Connect();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        st.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem occurred at executeUpdate operation: " + e);
        throw e;
    }finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(st);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in IT, add *another layer of abstraction* to solve your problem.

Meaning: you could have a class that is responsible for understanding "are we connected". It could gain that knowledge by periodically *ping* the DB server (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address) for ideas how to do that). So, before you ask to establish a connectin, you ask that "AreWeConnectedService" for its opinion.

That Service would basically work like this:

- it has an internal field "connected"
- it has an internal thread, that thread keeps periodically pinging the other side
- if ping fails you go `connected = false` (and probably you remember a timestamp)
- if ping works again at some point, you toggle the field agian

And then that service has a method to query that flag.

But of course, you could still lose the connection right after the service tells you "everything fine". Thus you have to further step back and fix the "other part" of your question: you have to use **another** thread then the SwingUX thread to perform that `getConnection()` call. Ideally, you might even use two threads: one that makes the actual call; and another one around that enforcing a timeout.

Beyond that: make sure that you read and understand what Oracle has to tell you about [Concurrency in JavaFx](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)! And another link - you might want to look into the [Circuit breaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) pattern, too.

Comment: Oh, yea that could definitely work. I'll see if I can implement this and return here with the result. Thanks so far!

Comment: Yea I've read some about concurrency in JavaFX. It basically comes down to the fact that the app thread is not threadsafe and therefore JavaFX provides it's own API for handling concurrency, if I'm not entirely wrong. Now I just gotta figure out how to properly utilize this.

Comment: Lets put it that way: any UI framework needs to deal with multi-threading by nature. Each framework has its own rules how go with threads therefore. You simply have to **understand** how things work.

Comment: Okay well, I'm not very experienced with threads in general. Could I possibly instead make the "AreWeConnectedService" return a boolean based on outcome and then try to connect while checking for the boolean, and eventually break out if we are able to connect?

EDIT: No, after some re-consideration, if I'm not entirely wrong I could still get the same problem when trying to connect to the DB, because the while condition would already hold but the actual internet connetion could be disrupted after we check for the connection but before the DB connection.

Comment: I simply forgot to push the button, and I thank you for the help you provided, it's much appreciated. However, I can't help but wonder if you're only here for the upvote with such comments as that.

Comment: In any case; let me know if you ran into real obstacles. I left my answer pretty broad; but if you run into a specific problem during implementation, it is always OK to write up another question ... and you can sure drop me a comment then.