# Combining ping scripts

Tags: java

I want to send packets while pinging, like when doing ping on Linux. I know it's possible as I've seen the scripts. I'm having a hard time putting 2 and 2 together.

Basically so it can:

A. Ping the IP

B. Send packets to IP.

So it should look like

```
Enter IP Address:
1.1.1.1
Sending Ping Request to 1.1.1.1
Host is reachable
Pinging Address
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4678 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3671 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2644 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1624 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=600 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=631 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=452 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 7 received, 30% packet loss, time 9136ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 451.531/2042.841/4678.491/1546.527 ms, pipe 5
```

Something to that effect.

Current Code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class expertping
 
{ 
  
  public static void sendPingRequest(String ipAddress) 
              throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
  { 
    InetAddress geek = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress); 
    System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress); 
    if (geek.isReachable(5000)) 
      System.out.println("Switch is reachable."); 
    else
      System.out.println("Unable to reach Switch."); 
  } 
  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
          throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{ 
  
  String ipAddress;
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Make sure to type in your switch ipv4, not your PC's.");
  System.out.println("Enter IP Address:");
  ipAddress=sc.next();
  sendPingRequest(ipAddress);
} 
}
```

This thread [How to ping an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/how-to-ping-an-ip-address) is similar and talks about the problem, but it may/may not talk about how to reintroduce it back into the code.

A person suggest looking [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pinging-ip-address-java-set-2by-creating-sub-process/) to find my answer for my troubles. The problem is I would like some help attaching to my current code, so it can actually actively connect to it, displaying the packets. My attempts just null out and only do 1 feature.

Comment: By the way [pinging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) an host already includes sending icmp packages to it, it's not simply trying to connect to it.

Comment: @MosheKatz Slightly, I think Frederico is right on this stance, its not actively trying to connect to it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Then I need to figure out how to make it actively connect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/how-to-ping-an-ip-address